# How can I resolve multiple python installs?

Tags: 18.04, software-installation, python

I recently installed python 3.8.2 on to my Ubuntu 18.04 laptop. However, I then found the built-in python 3.6 installation and I don't know how to remove 3.8. I've tried `make uninstall` because it was built from source, but this didn't work. Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: Have you installed it in /usr/local/ ? If so you can manually delete python3.8 files in the bin/  , lib/ , and perhaps include/ of the /usr/local. "Make uninstall" is a standard way to delete a program compiled and installed from source , but some projects don't configure their makefiles accordingly. So I think the best way is to delete them manually.

Comment: Or if you still have the output of "make install" in your terminal , you can see what files and directories belong to python3.8 (lines like this : " -- Installing : ....... " )

Comment: I don't have the output, but would this cause issues where Linux thinks the command still exists, but it doesn't. I ask because I know that mycroft ai will install 3.8 again, but from apt - a better way.

Comment: What do you mean by "command still exists, but it doesn't" ? And have you installed python 3.8 via mycroft ?

Comment: I that will linux still think that `python38` is still a command, and also will it go back to `python3` meaning 3.6. I mentioned mycrofft because it will install 3.8 again.

Comment: If you delete the python3.8 binary file , then you'd be able to use your previous python via python3 .

Comment: The 2nd duplicate link is not essential, but I added because the command to install python3.8 from the default Ubuntu repositories is `sudo apt install python3.8`